# With nested Bindings in C# WPF ItemsControls is it possible to find a DataContext's parent?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am still fairly new to binding in WPF, and I am curious to know how to properly determine the parent of a given DataContext when it it's binding is nested.

I have created some sample code to reconstruct my problem. But unfortunately the INotifyPropertyChanged (which is required for the presentation layer to update) makes the constructors rather large, the data in this example code is simply:

The parents list contains:

[image: Parent Tree]

While the presentation is laid out with the MainWindow presenting each parent in a ParentUserControl.  Which in turn then presents the associated Children in a ChildUserControl.

With the code as follows, what is the best way for the code behind to identify the parent of the button that was pressed?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingProblem">
   <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <local:ParentUserControl></local:ParentUserControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:  (Also contains definitions for ParentClass and ChildClass)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace BindingProblem
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<ParentClass> data = new List<ParentClass>(){
                new ParentClass()
                {
                    ParentName = "Parent A",
                    children = new List<ChildClass>(){
                        new ChildClass() {ChildName = "Child 1"},
                        new ChildClass() {ChildName = "Child 2"}
                    }
                },
                new ParentClass()
                {
                    ParentName = "Parent B",
                    children = new List<ChildClass>(){
                        new ChildClass() {ChildName = "Child 3"},
                        new ChildClass() {ChildName = "Child 4"}
                    }
                }
        };

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = data;
        }
    }

    public class ParentClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p) { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p)); }

        private string _ParentName;
        public string ParentName
        {
            get { return _ParentName; }
            set { _ParentName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ParentName"); }
        }

        private List<ChildClass> _children;
        public List<ChildClass> children
        {
            get { return _children; }
            set { _children = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("children"); }
        }
    }

    public class ChildClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }

        private string _ChildName;
        public string ChildName
        {
            get { return _ChildName; }
            set { _ChildName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ChildName"); }
        }
    }
}
```

ParentUserControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingProblem.ParentUserControl" 
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingProblem">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParentName}"></TextBlock>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding children}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <local:ChildUserControl></local:ChildUserControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

ParentUserControl.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace BindingProblem
{
    public partial class ParentUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public ParentUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ChildUserControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingProblem.ChildUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel Margin="20,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChildName}"></TextBlock>
        <Button Content="Click Me" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

ChildUserControl.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;


namespace BindingProblem
{
    public partial class ChildUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public ChildUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((ChildClass)DataContext).ChildName);// this works to get my data for the child
            // How would I find the ParentName Feild of the parent assosiated to this child.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options of achieving this:

- You can walk up the visual tree in code behind by recursively calling the method GetParent of the [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx) until you get the type of ParentUserControl. You can then access its DataContext property.
- You can bind to the parent’s DataContext in XAML with `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type yourNamespace:ParentUserControl}}, Path=DataContext}`. If you bind this to the Tag property of the button, you could then get the reference from code behind.
- You can create a property on the child view model of the type ICommand. The instance of this command is then created by the parent view model and the parent view models injects a reference to itself when doing so. Then it sets the child‘s property to the new command object. I this approach you don‘t use event handlers on the ChildUserControl, but bind the Button‘s command property to the command of the child view model. That way the command code will have a reference to the parent view model.

Comment: Binding a ChildUserControl element's DataContext to the parent worked perfectly.  Thank-you very much.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is, each child can be given ParentName, so your ChildClass can become

```
public class ChildClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }

    public string ParentName {get;set;}

    private string _ChildName;
    public string ChildName
    {
        get { return _ChildName; }
        set { _ChildName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ChildName"); }
    }
}
```

when you instantiate ChildClass to add as items to the parent's children, just provide them the name of parent in which they are being added,
and then in the Click Event

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(((sender as Button).DataContext as ChildClass).ParentName);
    }
```

Comment: If you take this approach, I would recommend keeping a reference to the parent object itself and getting the name from the actual property on the parent object. Otherwise, changing the name in the parent object won‘t automatically be reflected in child objects.

Comment: Thank-you for the feedback, unfortunately the actual data that I am using has significantly more fields than this simplified model, and several of the fields will influence the ChildUserControl.